# Put form displayed with position absolute out moblte into a modal bootstrap button for mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I got an issue and need some help,

There is also a button on the big screen but can be disable for larger screen and active for mobile.

I am trying to put a form who is displayed on the right side on a banner in position absolute and set hidden for mobile to a modal when click on the button on mobile it will show the form hidden into the modal.
I heard Jquery clone append can do it but it is not showing correctly.I want it unhide the form for mobile inside the modal.like ->clone,append,show and hide when re-click.make sense?

my issue is for mobile not larger screen.

Here is the code:

```
<header>

    <img class="full" src="img/header2.jpg" border="0"/>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption custom">
            <a href="javascript:toggleDiv('form');">
                <button data-toggle="modal" id="pop" class="btn btn-xl custom" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">
                    现在下单<span class="arrow"><img src="img/icon-gt-sml.png"></span></button>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Large modal -->
    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="form" class="well hidden-xs">
        ...
        </form>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleDiv(divId) {
        $("#" + divId).toggleClass('hidden-xs');
    }
</script>
```

CSS large screen:

```
.well {
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 2px solid #b40623;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 40px;
    top: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

CSS mobile:

```
.well {
    right: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe provide an example (on CodePen/JsFiddle) to show what exactly is going wrong? 'Not showing correctly' isn't very helpful. If you really can't get it set up, then please explain what's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it by using JS:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function findBootstrapEnvironment() {
    var envs = ['xs', 'sm', 'md', 'lg'];

    $el = $('<div>');
    $el.appendTo($('body'));

    for (var i = envs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var env = envs[i];

        $el.addClass('hidden-' + env);
        if ($el.is(':hidden')) {
            $el.remove();
            return env
        }
    }
}

  $(document).ready(function(){

    var b = findBootstrapEnvironment();
    // Just for mobile
    if (b == 'xs') {
        $(".bs-example-modal-lg").on("show.bs.modal",function(){
            $("#modal .modal-body").empty();
            $("#form form").clone().appendTo("#modal .modal-body");
        });
    }else{
        $(".custom button[data-toggle]").removeAttr("data-toggle");
    }

  });
    </script>
```